# Issue in installing truffle-hdwallet-provider

Tags: solidity, truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp, openzeppelin-contracts

I am trying to install "truffle-hdwallet-provider" using the command "npm i truffle-hdwallet-provider --save".

I am getting the beow mentioned error. Please assist me in resolving this.

```
truffle-hdwallet-provider@0.0.6 requires a peer of truffle@4.x but none is installed
```

[image]

Version details:
NPM - 5.6.0
NODE - v8.11.3

Comment: Well there are a number of things you can try such as updating or downgrading your version of node, updating windows build tools because that is what node-gvp uses?

Additionally, please include your node and npm version as that might be version specific.

Comment: Version details:
NPM - 5.6.0
NODE - v8.11.3

Comment: I even tried updated the NPM and NODE to latest version.

Comment: Perhaps try installing truffle first and then truffle wallet. npm install truffle

Comment: The problems is that scrypt (a dependency of truffle) fails to install. 

From the error message the compiler is not correctly configured. Make sure to follow this https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows when setting up the compiler.